# LDAP: How to reset value of pwdReset field

Tags: java, ldap, tivoli

I am trying to write an application which would offer user to manage users on LDAP system. One feature of this is the functionality "*Forgot Password*".

1. User uses my app to Reset his password
2. I ask some security questions and if they are correct, I redirect him to new screen - new password screen.
3. User provides new password only (as he has forgotten his old one)
4. I use admin Context and reset the user password (using `modifyAttributes(..)`).
5. The LDAP system, set `pwdReset` to `true` indicating that password was changed by admin and must be changed by user.

Now, I do want to set this to false, coz I don't want user to change his password again (as he already did in above steps), so I explicitly modify it to false. But I get error

```
javax.naming.directory.SchemaViolationException: [LDAP: error code 65 - Object Class Violation]; remaining name 'cn=XXXX,ou=XXXXOU,O=XXXX'
```

**What is the way around ?** Is there some other alternative ?

For refernce, the code to reset `pwdReset` is as under:

```
        List<ModificationItem> modsList = new ArrayList<ModificationItem>();
        BasicAttribute attribute = new BasicAttribute(ATTR_PASSWORDRESET, "false");
        modsList.add(new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, attribute));
        ModificationItem [] modsArr = modsList.toArray(new ModificationItem[modsList.size()]);
        modsArr = modsList.toArray(new ModificationItem[modsList.size()]);
        this.adminCtx.modifyAttributes(userName, modsArr);
```

[image]

And here is my `pwdPolicy`

[image]
[image]

Comment: So you aren't using [tag:OpenLDAP] at all, you are using an IBM product? Don't tag indiscriminately.

Answer (score 2):

I've just spent two weeks proving to myself that OpenLDAP doesn't actually do step #5 at all, despite what the wording of the RFC draft appears to mean. I also found a message in the OpenLDAP Mail archives confirming that they think it isn't supposed to do that. So what is happening is that there is no `pwdReset` attribute to set to false, so you're getting a schema violation trying to *add* it with that value. So, all you have to do is nothing.

It would probably be safer just to set `pwdReset` to null, which removes it completely, or just remove it with `DirContext.REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE`. My code doesn't use `ModificationItem`, which is another clue, more like:

```
BasicAttributes attributes = new BasicAttributes(ATTR_PASSWORDRESET, null);
this.adminCtx.modifyAttributes(userName, attrs);
```

The above also means that if you want it set to `TRUE` you have to do so yourself.

Comment: I am on a LDAP system, and it does set `pwdReset` to true, when I (as admin) is resetting user's password. I tried your code, but it gives same exception

Comment: I added screenshot

Comment: Btw, i believe, that in your case OpenLDAP was not doing anything coz password policy wasn't enabled

Comment: The password policy overlay in my system has been enabled for six years. I am changing the password with the extended password-modify operation.

Comment: then I am not sure why it isn't setting `pwdReset` to `true` in my case... coz it is setting it to `true` in my case..

Comment: Can you post your actual policy in your question, and also your code for changing the password?

Comment: The code is the one in the question.. what do you mean by `actual policy` ?

Comment: I mean the content of the `pwdPolicy` entry: the settings of all the policy variables, e.g. `pwdMustChange`. I don't see any actual real code for changing the password.

Comment: But still not with the change-password code. But it all seems to be irrelevant as you aren't using OpenLDAP, despite your tag, and I am.

Comment: **So why the [tag:openldap] tag?** I've wasted a lot of time here assuming we were using the same LDAP server. We aren't.